# iOS removeFromSuperview if not added to superview doesn't throw an error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I tried `removeFromSuperview` on a view that had not been added as a subview but Xcode 4 didn't throw any error. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: It isn't what I would expect, but it does not appear to be inconsistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Xcode 4 wouldn't do anything at all. That's the IDE. It has nothing to do with the runtime behavior of your app.

Secondly, the documentation for `-removeFromSuperview` states

> If the receiver’s superview is not nil, the superview releases the receiver.

What part of this would lead you to expect `-removeFromSuperview` to throw an exception if the view has no superview?

In any case, the answer is yes, this is normal. `-removeFromSuperview` does not throw exceptions.

Comment: Well with Xcode 4 I mean the console outputting error. But in my case the receiver's superview is not nil. The superview exists but the subview that I'm `removeFromSuperview` has not been added to the superview. That's why I'm wondering why it doesn't output any errors?

Comment: by definition it's not an error - - - it's not good programming practice (in this language) to use exceptions to inform of expected situations.  throwing an exception takes you out of the call stack framework and *will* leak memory; if we did it to handle common "exceptions" it would be bad - - - the framework designers decided that `removeFromSuperview` when you aren't in a view hierarchy is a no-op, you can validly argue the other way, but that won't change someone else's mind … 10 years ago

Comment: So if I'm `removeFromSuperview` a view that hasn't been added as a subview is not "bad" programming from my side then? Is there a way to check if a view has been added as a subview?

Comment: @Peter: You can check it quite easily by looking at `view.superview`. If that's nil, it hasn't been added to a view.